# Easy tool to convert html5/js web app to native Android and iOS app?

Tags: android, web-apps, javascript, software-development, ios

I've got a bunch of web apps using HTML5/JavaScript, and I would love to have these also as native Android and iOS apps.

I have tons of experience with developing web stuff in JavaScript. However I have absolutely *zero* experience with Android or iOS or Java or ObjectiveC development.

What's the easiest way to go about this? Suppose my web app consists of a .html file with a bunch of .js files and some resources (images and stuff). Is there a simple application or tool or some fool proof method to convert this into a .apk and .app file for Android and iOS ?

Comment: I would imagine this to be quite tough as js is scripted and all platforms for mobile use oo languages with strict typing.

Comment: @GabrielFair It doesn't necessarily have to be a full conversion on language level. It can also be an emulation, or even a generic placeholder app with a web view where my html5/js is rendered inside. There are plenty of ways to go about this that would work fine. I know there are solutions for this, just wondering about the easiest / most fool proof one.